# onchange() does not seem to work in jquery for dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

```html
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.Label("Role 1", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, ViewBag.Name as SelectList,"Choose Roles", new{ @id = "drp1" })
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.Label("Role 2", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name1, ViewBag.Name1 as SelectList, "Choose Roles", new { @id = "drp2" })
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.Label("Role 3", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name2, ViewBag.Name2 as SelectList, "Choose Roles", new { @id = "drp3" })
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" />
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="~/Employee/Index">Cancel</a>
  </div>
```

I have 2 Drop list. When I select options other than "Choose roles" in dropdown1, dropdown2 will be enabled. But when i click back "Choose Roles" in dropdown1, I want to disable the dropdown2. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
@
section Scripts { < script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
      $('#drp1').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#drp2').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#drp3').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#drp1').change(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') != "Choose Roles") {
          $('#drp2').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $('#drp2').prop('disabled',
            true);
          $('#drp3').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
      $('#drp2').change(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') != "Choose Roles") {
          $('#drp3').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $('#drp3').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
    }) < /script>
          }
    </div >
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>create - My ASP.NET Application</title>
  <link href="/Content/css?v=0SmSUbKHtL7l80jQRHND36iqfshRxhpCCevkkcBpTzo1" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Finance</a> 
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post">
          <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CAE0mh8xaWk0K-seziLGNuiTKGCpK4XOuz0m8Ol-JM16MLDNlPszIZ8lbU0AZeKu9xzyBfrbmzVJoQV2tQjv7Ic4LnLU9JZ1uNQ4WV990eaK2ZVaUY1AFTU7WtxY5tOwOQCk9iMVZR-AzSgjIt1-ZA2" />
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">Hello Mahesh@Bhandari.com!</a>

            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/Profile/edit" title="View Profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width: 1600px; height: auto">
    <div style="width: 1200px; float: right">


      <form action="/Employee/create" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="nzuPBTYGPRvqWXduxC3xOzesSfc5NxcJb9Wo3aaQa9wSVM7gCidc4kllcHSKHDM1KBcCCmdL0ZdwGT1TmrriCgmS-ntyJc2eRnmmNpY6IaXptTUQyV7H0D9pFMCXqzg98oGC56UEImawOTTO0dhx-Q2" />
        <hr />
        <div class="validation-summary-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-summary="true">
          <ul>
            <li style="display:none"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="First_Name">First Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="contact_FirstName" name="contact.FirstName" type="text" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Last_Name">Last Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="contact_LastName" name="contact.LastName" type="text" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Gender">Gender</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="contact_Gender" name="contact.Gender" type="text" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="City">City</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="contact_City" name="contact.City" type="text" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Country">Country</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="contact_Country" name="contact.Country" type="text" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Email">Email</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Password">Password</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Confirm_Password">Confirm Password</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" type="password" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Role_1">Role 1</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="drp1" name="Name">
              <option value="">Choose Roles</option>
              <option value="Sales Person">Sales Person</option>
              <option value="Store Admin">Store Admin</option>
              <option value="Tailor">Tailor</option>
              <option value="Company Admin">Company Admin</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Role_2">Role 2</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="drp2" name="Name1">
              <option value="">Choose Roles</option>
              <option value="Sales Person">Sales Person</option>
              <option value="Store Admin">Store Admin</option>
              <option value="Tailor">Tailor</option>
              <option value="Company Admin">Company Admin</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Role_3">Role 3</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="drp3" name="Name2">
              <option value="">Choose Roles</option>
              <option value="Sales Person">Sales Person</option>
              <option value="Store Admin">Store Admin</option>
              <option value="Tailor">Tailor</option>
              <option value="Company Admin">Company Admin</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" />
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Employee/Index">Cancel</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 280px; float: left; margin-left: 200px">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" style="background-color: #424A5D; ">
        <li class="active" style="width: 200px"><a href="/Home/">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li id="accordion" class="dropdown" style="width: 200px">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="dropdown-toggle">
         Super Admin<i class="caret"></i>
        </a>
          <ul style="height: auto;" id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse dropdown collapse">
            <li class="drop active"><a href="/Company/Index" class="whitedrop">Company</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="accordion2" class="dropdown" style="width: 200px">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo" class="dropdown-toggle">
           Company Admin<i class="caret"></i>
        </a>
          <ul style="height: auto;" id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse dropdown collapse">
            <li class="drop active"><a href="/Customer/Index" class="whitedrop">Customer</a>
            </li>
            <li class="drop active"><a href="/Employee/Index" class="whitedrop">Employee</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active" style="width: 200px"><a href="/Store/">Store</a>
        </li>
      </ul>




    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="/bundles/jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1"></script>

  <script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=2Fz3B0iizV2NnnamQFrx-NbYJNTFeBJ2GM05SilbtQU1"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#drp1').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#drp2').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#drp3').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#drp1').change(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') != "Choose Roles") {
          $('#drp2').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $('#drp2').prop('disabled', true);
          $('#drp3').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
      $('#drp2').change(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') != "Choose Roles") {
          $('#drp3').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $('#drp3').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
    })
  </script>


  <!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
  <script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"24be147473e64b5a8ae4fc7c874f725a"}
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:5767/972fdbb3c96e4f889f6df05c6843f555/browserLink" async="async"></script>
  <!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** event handler

```js
   
$('#drp1').change(function() {
  //disabling dropdown if value is "Choose roles", using prop() method
  $('#drp2').prop('disabled', this.value == "Choose roles" ? true : false)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drp1">
  <option value="other">other</option>
  <option value="Choose roles">Choose roles</option>
  <option value="other">other</option>
</select>
<select id="drp2">
  <option>Choose roles</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i was hoping you could solve in the code i have posted.I  am new to scripting

Comment: I am not able to post images because reputation is too low: it says

Comment: i don't mean the screenshot.... i mean the code shown in the browser... you can copy them by using view page source option